# Neovim-Tmux Navigation Plugin with LazyVim not working as expected

Tags: lua, tmux, neovim

I am trying to install the plugin https://github.com/alexghergh/nvim-tmux-navigation so I can easily switch between Tmux panes and Neovim panes. I am using the default lazyvim installation plus the additions I have mentioned https://www.lazyvim.org/installation

Currently, I am able to use ctrl+hjkl to move between neovim panes using the current setup in a normal session without tmux.
BUT
During a tmux session, I am only able to move between the tmux panes and not to/between the neovim sessions.
So this implementation that I have seems to not be working on the tmux side since the NvimTmux commands are executing as expected. I was hoping I could be pointed in the right direction towards fixing this tmux issue.

```
lua/plugins/tmux.lua

return {
  "alexghergh/nvim-tmux-navigation",
  event = "VeryLazy",
  config = function()
    local nvim_tmux_nav = require("nvim-tmux-navigation")
    nvim_tmux_nav.setup({
      disable_when_zoomed = true,
      -- defaults to false
      keybindings = {
        left = "<C-h>",
        down = "<C-j>",
        up = "<C-k>",
        right = "<C-l>",
        last_active = "<C-\\>",
        next = "<C-Space>",
      },
    })
  end,
}
```

---

```
lua/config/keymap.lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-h>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateLeft<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-j>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateDown<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-k>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateUp<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-l>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateRight<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-\\>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateLastActive<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-Space>", "<Cmd>NvimTmuxNavigateNavigateNext<CR>", { silent = true })
```

---

```
~/.tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix

unbind %
bind | split-window -h 

unbind '"'
bind - split-window -v

unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

bind -r j resize-pane -D 5
bind -r k resize-pane -U 5
bind -r l resize-pane -R 5
bind -r h resize-pane -L 5

bind -r m resize-pane -Z

set -g mouse on

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection # start selecting text with "v"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection # copy text with "y"

unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane # don't exit copy mode when dragging with mouse

# remove delay for exiting insert mode with ESC in Neovim
set -sg escape-time 10

# tpm plugin
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'

# list of tmux plugins
# set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
# THIS IS WHERE THE NEW CODE FOR NAVIGATION IS
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h' 'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j' 'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k' 'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l' 'select-pane -R'

tmux_version='$(tmux -V | sed -En "s/^tmux ([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).*/\1/p")'

if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"

bind-key -n 'C-Space' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-Space' 'select-pane -t:.+'

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-h' select-pane -L
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-j' select-pane -D
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-k' select-pane -U
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-l' select-pane -R
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-\' select-pane -l
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-Space' select-pane -t:.+


# END FANCY STUFF <---------

set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect' # persist tmux sessions after computer restart
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum' # automatically saves sessions for you every 15 minutes

set -g @themepack 'powerline/default/cyan'

set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
set -g @continuum-restore 'on'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Solved the problem, Fig causes Tmux to not pick up on the different sessions running since Figterm overrides the Vim process. https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/issues/339
Used a custom script to help tmux find it. See above issue.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: MacOS, but it shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: just noticed it's using some commands like sed/grep. not sure if they behave the same on different OS. just FYI.

Comment: i tried and it worked fine for me (macos, tmux 3.3a, nvim 0.9.1)

Comment: That's the same versions I have running for tmux and neovim. Did you use the same configuration in this post? What terminal are you running? could it be iterm?

Comment: yes i'm using iterm.

Comment: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/issues/339